# How to use same session on one laravel application using 2 different domains

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have one Laravel 5.3 application. using the same Database/Server/App. 
But im using 2 different domains (**not subdomains**) for the same app.

domain1.com
domain2.com

I want when the user logins on domain1.com, that session to work also on domain2.com. But wont work, wouldnt there be a simple solution to this, as im using the same laravel app?

Im using routes to define what domain what routes to use

example like this

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'domain1'), function() {
//routes goes here
}

Route::group(array('domain' => 'domain2'), function() {
//routes goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you added domain name in session then you can set `null` in `session.php` in `config` folder and clear session of existing (laravel 5.5)

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

for older version

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,
```

**Updated**

if its still not working then save session in database
Run command tp generate table

```
php artisan session:table
```

//below command will update changes

```
composer dump-autoload
```

php artisan migrate

change in **.env** to `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

also modify **config/session.php**

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database') 
'domain' => '.com'
```

Comment: nope i didnt add anything there. Its set to null  :/

Comment: can you try to change 'domain' => '.com' to .com only since its a different domain

Comment: i added SESSION_DRIVER=database ,  but still when i login on domain1.com is not log me automatically on domain2.com...  If i add also  'domain' => '.co.uk'  it wont log me in at all, only if i set it to null works.. but still not keeping the session in 2 domains.. hm

Comment: @mendi19.okay. i have not got chance to test your case.will see if i get change i ll check.